# How do I uncurry a function in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying

Recently, I have studied 'Programming language' using standard [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_%28programming_language%29), and I've learned currying method(or something), so I applied it in Python.
The below is simple function and currying.

```
def range_new(x, y):
    return [i for i in range(x, y+1)]

def curry_2(f):
    return lambda x: lambda y: f(x, y)

def uncurry_2(f):
    pass # I don't know it...

print(range_new(1, 10))
curried_range = curry_2(range_new)
countup = curried_range(1)
print(countup(10))
print(curried_range(1)(10))
```

The result is below. And it works well; with `curry_2` we can make a new function(`countup`). But, then I want to make an uncurried function.
However, I don't know how I can make it.
How can I do it?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: By uncurry do you mean - you'd like to create a function called "countup" that just accepts (x, y) as parameters? Or do you mean, you'd like to "undo" one of the calls to a curried function? Also note, that the above is something between currying and partial application. With a generic implementation of currying you should be able to accept any number of arguments any time the function is called.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What would the result of uncurrying be? That you get a new reference to `range_new`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest solution is to wrap the curried function again with code that uncurries it:

```
def uncurry_2(f):
    return lambda x, y: f(x)(y)

uncurried_range = uncurry_2(curried_range)
print(uncurried_range(1, 10))
```

Comment: It's possibly worth mentioning that in the context of Standard ML which the OP references, this is usually what uncurrying means.

Answer (score 8):

It's not exactly good style but you can access the variables in the closure using the (maybe CPython-only) [`__closure__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-34) attribute of the returned `lambda`:

```
>>> countup.__closure__[0].cell_contents
<function __main__.range_new>
```

This accesses the content of the innermost closure (the variable used in the innermost `lambda`) of your function `curry_2` and thus returns the function you used there.

However in production code you shouldn't use that. It would be better to create a class (or function) for currying that supports accessing the uncurried function (which is something `lambda` does not provide). However some functools in Python support accessing the "decorated" function, for example `partial`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> countup = partial(range_new, 1)
>>> print(countup(10))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> countup.func
<function __main__.range_new>
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe by uncurry you mean you'd like to allow the function to accept more arguments. Have you considered using the "partial" function? It allows you to use as many arguments as desired when calling the method.

```
from functools import partial

def f(a, b, c, d):
  print(a, b, c, d)

g = partial(partial(f, 1, 2), 3)
g(4)
```

Implementing it should be pretty straight forward

```
def partial(fn, *args):
  def new_func(*args2):
    newArgs = args + args2
    fn(*newArgs)

  return new_func;
```

Note both the code presented in the original question, and the code above is known as partial application. Currying is more flexible than this typically - here's how you can do it with Python 3 (it is more tricky in Python 2).

```
def curry(fn, *args1):
  current_args = args1
  sig = signature(fn)

  def new_fn(*args2):
    nonlocal current_args
    current_args += args2
    if len(sig.parameters) > len(current_args):
      return new_fn
    else:
      return fn(*current_args)

  return new_fn

j = curry(f)
j(1)(2, 3)(4)
```

Now back to your code. range_new can now be used in a few new ways:

```
print(range_new(1, 10))
curried_range = curry(range_new)

countup = curried_range(1)
print(countup(10))

countup_again = curried_range
print(countup_again(1, 10))
```